# Compiling in Cygwin: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope, compiles fine in CentOS

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, g++4.8

I am running into issues compiling Linux-bound applications in Cygwin.

This error:

```
error: ‘EOF’ was not declared in this scope
```

is produced by the following code snippet

```
if (option == EOF) break;
```

Compiling this in CentOS directly produces no errors.

These are the g++ params passed by the make file:

```
-g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -std=gnu++11
```

GCC version on centOS:

```
 4.8.1 20130715
```

GCC version in Cygwin

```
 4.8.2
```

I am wondering if I am just missing some libraries in Cygwin, or if this is just a limitation of Cygwin and can't be resolved.

Comment: C++ code typically shouldn't use `EOF`, so it might be wise to look at the surrounding code and check it's using `EOF` correctly. `option` should be an `int` (or a larger signed integral type) and the code should not assume that `EOF` == `-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EOF` is defined in `stdio.h` / `cstdio`. What is likely happening is that you aren't including one of those headers, but *are* including, for example, `iostream`. Standard library headers are permitted to cause other headers to get included as well, and some implementations' `iostream` headers do exactly this, but not all. You shouldn't rely on it. If you use `EOF`, add an explicit include for the appropriate header in your own code. (Even if it isn't your code, which it isn't in this case, the modification required in the source code is the same.)

Comment: I added #include <cstdio> and it worked. Thank you!

This was actually starter code for a project give my the instructor. Since this is supposed to run in Linux, I guess the instructor did not test it in Windows, and being a windows guy I always seem to have to jerry-rig starter code to be able to work on it.